# How can I convert an int (UNIX timestamp) to datetime in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I have to create a table in SQL(I am using IntelliJ and Java), and the table must respect the following restrictions.

The table will contain the following columns:

- title - needs to be able to store letters, digits, and special characters
- news_description - needs to be able to store the text of the newsletter
- publication_date - needs to be able to store an integer (in UNIX system)

In addition to that, we have the following restrictions:

- the table will only be created if the table does not exist already
- the primary key will be the title
- 2 newsletters can't have the same description
- the news_description  can not be null
- in case the publication_date is not specified I need to set it to 27 April 2019 21:11:12 using UTC and the date must be in UNIX format

  ```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
       title VARCHAR,
       news_description TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
       publication_date "I don't know what I should write here in order to respect the last restriction"
       PRIMARY KEY(title)
    );
  ```

So my question is how can I respect all of the restriction I have said above all while I create the table

NOTE: This is homework I have and I can't add anything besides the table there, so I need to respect all of the restrictions within the creation of the table.

Comment: You have a speciifc question: "How to create a datetime column with default value in SQLite". So by making your question title "Creating an SQL table with specific restrictions" you reduce your chances to get an answer by half

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type of `publication_date` must be `INTEGER` and the default value for this column must be `1556399472` which is the equivalent timestamp for `27 April 2019 21:11:12`.
There is no problem to store dates as integers in SQLite because it is easy to retrieve a readable date by using the `'unixepoch'` modifier with the [Date And Time Functions of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
For example:

```
SELECT DATETIME(1556399472, 'unixepoch')
```

returns:

```
2019-04-27 21:11:12
```

Also there is no data type `VARCHAR` in SQLite. You should use `TEXT`.

So the create statement of your table can be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
  title TEXT,
  news_description TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  publication_date INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1556399472,
  PRIMARY KEY(title)
);
```

You may remove `NOT NULL` from the definition of `publication_date` if you want it to be nullable.

Comment: But if I do it like this, when I output my database info in the console, I will get 1556399472 and not 2019-04-27 21:11:12. Is there a way I can convert it within the create statement? @forpas

Comment: But one of the restrictions is: *publication_date - needs to be able to store an integer (in UNIX system)*. So you must store it as an integer. When you query the table, you can use the DATETIME() function to return it formatted as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. Isn't this that you want?

Comment: Somehow I still get a wrong answer on the platform which I am sending it on. I made sure I pay attention to all details so I don't have little mistakes. I will come with an explanation very soon

Comment: Nevermind... It was a little mistake, but now I remade it and it is correct. I appreciate the answer you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Unix format means Unix epoch format which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  This would be represented as a number:

```
publication_date int default 1556399472
```

That said, I would really recommend using the built-in `datetime` datatype:

```
publication_date datetime default '2019-04-27 21:11:12'
```

It is easy enough to convert to a Unix epoch when needed.

Comment: I don't think that there is a *built-in `datetime` datatype*, see https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Comment: Switching from `int` to `datetime` doesn't change much, only the affinity is now `numeric` instead of `integer` and `'2019-04-27 21:11:12'` is stored as `text` in either case.